# Packaging nuget package on VSTS 'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'

Tags: tfs, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Packaging a build use Nuget Packager in VSTS and i get the error:

### [error]'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library'.

Most of the hints that solves this involves updating nuget, but since I am building on Team Services I can't really do this.

Comment: I've hit this one as well today.

Comment: What're detail steps to reproduce this issue? Do you use Hosted agent? What's the project type you used? What's the result if you package it through NuGet.exe tool manually?

Comment: You can specify Nuget.exe tool path for NuGet Package task (Advanced)

Comment: I am building with Hosted Visual Studio 2017 agent and packaging using the nuget packager. I managed to solve it by using powershell to download nuget.exe and pointing the packager to this new instance.

Comment: @ruffen I get the same error in TFS on-premises, so tfs tag is valid for your question. Why did you delete it?

Comment: @FIL Because the question is phrased with VSTS in mind and not TFS. TFS is also different to VSTS because you inherently have more control over the machine that TFS is running on. A valid solution for TFS would be to upgrade nuget on the machine (same as a private build agent), instead of downloading a new each time, or adding the latest nuget to the repo, which seems to be the only viable solutions for VSTS with hosted build agents. I'm happy to add it back in if you make the case for it though.

Comment: @ruffen I see your point. Although the problem occurs in both VSTS and TFS with a slightly different solution, so the best way would be to mark the question with TFS and VSTS tags and provide an answer with a division into concerning VSTS and concerning TFS.

Comment: @FIL I added TFS tag back and changed my answer to reflect that my solution is for VSTS and not recommended for TFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue today.

### Using your own build agent

If you are using your own build agents (rather than the hosted agent) you can manually update the version of NuGet to the latest version. In my case, this has resolved my problems.

e.g. C:\agent\externals\nuget\nuget.exe

### Using the hosted agent

It's a bit messy but you could just upload the latest nuget.exe into the repo and set the NuGet Packager to use this.

Comment: This would work as well, I resolved it by using powershell to download the latest nuget and use this.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the nuget used by nuget packager is not the latest. After testing locally with latest nuget.exe everything worked so I added a new powershell release step. This solution is appropriate for VSTS, for TFS where you have access to the server I recommend upgrading nuget.exe on the server itself:

[image: Inline powershell build step - downloads nuget.exe]

This script downloads nuget.exe into the artifacts directory (and outputs the path to the nuget.exe so you can see where it is put.).

I then altered the Nuget Packager build step to use the freshly downloaded nuget.exe. 
[image: Nuget Packager build step with Custom path to nuget.exe]

Comment: Hello and thanks for this since it addresses the issue I'm having. Still I've never worked with powershells. Could you tell me or share a link so I know how to add a powershell step and how to alter the Nuget build so I can replicate what you did? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You pretty much just replicate what I added in the picture. I used the "Inline powershell" build script. Followed by the nuget packager build step, here you can just replicate what is in the second image.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone getting this in 2018, Microsoft have created a new version of the NuGet task that fixes this issue.  No need for powershell install steps.

[image]

Change the NuGet task version in your build step  version to 2.*

This caused some breaking changes for me, that I resolved with the following advanced settings

**Nuget Restore**

[image]

**Nuget Pack**

[image]

**Nuget push**

[image]

Comment: Are you using VSTS or a local TFS installation?